# Is SQL CTE performance depends on declaration order?

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, query-performance

Let's imagine two code drafts.

Fig. 1:

```sql
WITH
cte1 AS (
    SELECT a1, a2
    FROM A
    WHERE a_condition
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT b1, b2
    FROM B
    WHERE b_condition
)
SELECT
    a1, a2, b1, b2
FROM
    cte1, cte2
WHERE
    cross_condtion
```

Fig. 2:

```sql
WITH
cte_a AS (
    SELECT a1, a2
    FROM A
),
cte_b AS (
    SELECT b1, b2
    FROM B
)
SELECT
    a1, a2, b1, b2
FROM
    cte_a, cte_b
WHERE
    a_condition AND
    b_condition AND
    cross_condtion
```

Will execution plans be same on such queries? Or will in second case system get all data from A, all data from B and only then apply filters?

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Why are you asking us if the plans will be the same? Just get the execution plans and have a look

Comment: First of all, this is just an illustration, not an actual code, and for illustration purpose I bet it's ok to throw out non-essenstial details. Such as "proper, explicit, standard, readable JOIN syntax". I was asked not about the "JOIN syntax".

Second. My real code is very complex and huge, and I have some performance problems with it, and I am trying to localize them. And real execution plans also VERY complex and huge.

Answer (score 1):

The order of CTE clauses is typically not important.  Also CTEs are not always materialized, and the actual query plan does not have to follow the logical processing order implied by the CTEs.  In particular a WHERE clause criteria specified in the outer query can be pushed into the CTE subqueries.  Joins can be re-ordered, etc.

There's no *guarantee* that you'll get exactly the same plans for logically identical queries, but you shouldn't anticipate any impact on the query plans.